# Addition and subtraction of fractions (Precalculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify:
$\frac{3}{8(1-x)}+\frac{1}{8(1+x)}-\frac{1-x}{4(1+x^2)}-\frac{3}{4(x^2-1)}$

My attempt:

$=\frac{3}{8(1-x)}+\frac{1}{8(1+x)}-\frac{1-x}{4(1+x^2)}+\frac{3}{4(1-x^2)} $

$=\frac{3(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)+(1-x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)-(1-x)(2)(1-x)(1+x)(1-x^2)+3(2)(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{3(1+x)(1-x^4)+(1-x)(1-x^4)-(2-2x)(1-x^2)(1-x^2)+6(1-x^4)}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{(1-x^4)[(3+3x)+(1-x)+6]-(2-2x^2-2x+2x^3)(1-x^2)}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{(1-x^4)(2x+10)-(2-2x^2-2x^2+2x^4-2x+2x^3+2x^3-2x^4)}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{2x+10-2x^5-10x^4-(2-4x^2-2x+4x^3)}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{2x+10-2x^5-10x^4-2+4x^2+2x-4x^3}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{-2x^5-10x^4-4x^3+4x^2+4x+8}{8(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}$

$=\frac{-x^5-5x^4-2x^3+2x^2+2x+4}{4(1-x^2)(1-x^4)}$

But the answer is given as $\frac{2+x+3x^2}{2(1-x^4)}$. I don't know where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it helps to consider that $(x^2−1)=(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: There are additional factors that are multiplied in. From where you landed, consider factoring 5th degree polynomial and eliminating factors by comparing with denominator. This may also help you find unnecessary multiplication of factors you did earlier.

Comment: This means that in the 2nd line (the longest) you can cancel $(1-x^2)$ from both numerator and denominator, and this will simplify the computations.

Comment: Just to expand on what @MauroALLEGRANZA said note you want the least common multiple as the denominator and the least common multiple here is $(1+x^2)(1-x^2)$.

Comment: Having said that, the error is in 5th line: last term on the right on top must be $-2x^5$. In this way, the wrong term $x^5$ disappear.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach
$$\frac{3}{8(1-x)}+\frac{1}{8(1+x)}-\frac{1-x}{4(1+x^2)}-\frac{3}{4(x^2-1)}$$
$$= \frac{3}{8(1-x)}+\frac{1}{8(1+x)}-\frac{1-x}{4(1+x^2)}+\frac{3}{4(1-x^2)}$$
$$=\frac{2x+4}{8(1-x^2)}-\frac{1-x}{4(1+x^2)}+\frac{3}{4(1-x^2)}$$
$$=\frac{2x+1+3x^2}{4(1-x^4)}+\frac{3(1+x^2)}{4(1-x^4)}$$
$$=\frac{2+x+3x^2}{2(1-x^4)}$$